# Boost.Graph - algo.is_optimal() assertion

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am trying to implement a program that detects [arbitrage trading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage) opportunities using a *minimum cost flow* algorithm. This algorithm is implemented in Boost.Graph in the form of `boost::push_relabel_max_flow()` followed by a call to `boost::cycle_canceling()`.

The following is the code I have already, leaving out the `boost::cycle_canceling`-part because my program dies before reaching the function.

```
    #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
    #include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/cycle_canceling.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/directed_graph.hpp>
    #include <boost/config.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>



    typedef boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> Traits;

    struct st_order {
        double price;
        double amount;
        std::string type;
    };

    struct VertexProps {
        unsigned int id;
    };

    struct EdgeProps {
        double capacity;
        double residual_capacity;
        double weight;
        Traits::edge_descriptor reverse;
    };

    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProps, EdgeProps > DirectedGraph;

    int main() {


        DirectedGraph g;

        // ETH / BTC
        std::vector<st_order> trades{
            st_order{0.0101,10.0,"SELL"},
            st_order{0.01,3.0,"BUY"},
            st_order{0.0102,5.0,"SELL"},
            st_order{0.2,42.0,"BUY"},
        };


        std::vector<boost::graph_traits<DirectedGraph>::vertex_descriptor> vertices;
        for(unsigned int vertex_index = 0; vertex_index < trades.size(); vertex_index++)
        {
            vertices.push_back(boost::add_vertex({vertex_index}, g));
        }


        std::map<DirectedGraph::vertex_descriptor, std::map<DirectedGraph::vertex_descriptor, Traits::edge_descriptor>> edges;


int ifirst = 0;
for(auto& first : vertices)
{
    int isecond = 0;
    for(auto& second : vertices)
    {

        if(first == second || trades[ifirst].type.compare(trades[isecond].type) == 0)
        {
            isecond++;
            continue;
        }

        double amount = trades[isecond].amount;

        if(trades[isecond].type.compare("SELL") == 0)
            amount = amount * trades[isecond].price;

        edges[first][second] = boost::add_edge(first, second, {amount, amount, (trades[isecond].price / trades[ifirst].price)} , g).first;
        std::cout << "Add Edge: From " << first << " to " << second << std::endl;

        isecond++;
    }
    ifirst++;
}


for(auto& i : vertices)
{
    for(auto& j : vertices)
    {
        if(i == j)
            continue;

        if(edges.find(i) != edges.end() && edges[i].find(j) != edges[i].end())
        {
            if(edges.find(j) == edges.end() || edges[j].find(i) == edges[j].end())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("No return edge found: "+std::to_string(i)+" "+std::to_string(j));
            }

            auto edge = boost::edge(i,j,g).first;
            g[edge].reverse = edges[i][j];

        }
    }
}



        double flow = boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, vertices[0], vertices[1],
                boost::get(&EdgeProps::capacity, g),
                boost::get(&EdgeProps::residual_capacity, g),
                boost::get(&EdgeProps::reverse, g),
                boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g)
            );

// Now boost::cycle_canceling() would follow

    std::cout << "END << std::endl;
    return 0;
    };
```

The "normal" output of my program is:

```
Add Edge: From 0 to 1
Add Edge: From 0 to 3
Add Edge: From 1 to 0
Add Edge: From 1 to 2
Add Edge: From 2 to 1
Add Edge: From 2 to 3
Add Edge: From 3 to 0
Add Edge: From 3 to 2
```

As flowchart:

[image]

My program asserts in the `push_relabel_max_flow`-function. The following is the complete error code (which is printed at **runtime**):

```
    /usr/local/include/boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp:707: typename
 boost::property_traits<IndexMap>::value_type 
boost::push_relabel_max_flow(Graph&, typename 
boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, typename 
boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor, CapacityEdgeMap, 
ResidualCapacityEdgeMap, ReverseEdgeMap, VertexIndexMap) [with Graph = 
boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, 
VertexProps, EdgeProps>; CapacityEdgeMap = 
boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long 
unsigned int, EdgeProps, double EdgeProps::*>; ResidualCapacityEdgeMap = 
boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, double, double&, long 
unsigned int, EdgeProps, double EdgeProps::*>; ReverseEdgeMap = 
boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, 
boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, long unsigned int>, 
boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, long unsigned int>&, long
 unsigned int, EdgeProps, boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::directed_tag, 
long unsigned int> EdgeProps::*>; VertexIndexMap = 
boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<VertexProps, long unsigned int>; typename 
boost::property_traits<IndexMap>::value_type = double; typename 
boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int]: Assertion
 `algo.is_optimal()' failed.
```

At the very end of the message you can see **Assertion: algo.is_optimal() failed**. I have absolutly no idea what this means.

In the source file (*boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp*) it is defined as:

```
bool is_optimal() {
        // check if mincut is saturated...
        global_distance_update();
        return get(distance, src) >= n;
      }
```

I have googled it and didn't find anything. Did I pass my parameters the wrong way? Is it because I use `double` as capacity (although, if I recall correctly, the "[documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/push_relabel_max_flow.html)" described it as possible to use a `double` for the capacity)? 
Also, I have discovered this sentence in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/push_relabel_max_flow.html):

> The CapacityEdgeMap argument cap must map each edge in E to a positive
>   number, **and each edge in E^T to 0**.

What does the bold part mean? Does it mean that I have to set the capacity of all outgoing edges from the sink-vertex to 0?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular algorithm. I ran you code though and it looks like `is_optimal` is part of push-relabel algorithm not boost as I thought originally. My guess is that it could have to do with the topology of your graph. I didn't have time to go through your graph building code. Are you sure this topology is correct for this type of problem? You might consider staring with a minimal working example of the algorithm.

Comment: I edited my post with some more information and a diagram. I am pretty sure I can use this algorithm for my graph.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the reverse edges' capacities to 0.

So you need:

```
auto edge = boost::edge(i,j,g).first;
g[edge].reverse = edges[i][j];
g[edges[i][j]].capacity = 0;
```

I'm not sure why this is though. Looking into [read_dimacs.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/graph/read_dimacs.hpp) I noticed that they create their reverse edges and give them 0 capacity. About 3/4 of the way down the page:

```
capacity[e1] = cap;
capacity[e2] = 0;
reverse_edge[e1] = e2;
reverse_edge[e2] = e1;
```

Likely without this constraint, the algorithm will try to treat these as normal edges. The portion of the documentation that you quote describes this, but it's not completely obvious.

> There are several special requirements on the input graph and property
>   map parameters for this algorithm. First, the directed graph G=(V,E)
>   that represents the network must be augmented to include the reverse
>   edge for every edge in E. That is, the input graph should be Gin =
>   (V,{E U E^T}). The ReverseEdgeMap argument rev must map each edge in
>   the original graph to its reverse edge, that is (u,v) -> (v,u) for all
>   (u,v) in E. The CapacityEdgeMap argument cap must map each edge in E
>   to a positive number, and each edge in E^T to 0.

I think here E^T means *transpose* not target. You have to know that the transpose of a directed adjacency matrix is actually the reverse of the all the edges. That is why they say that the input graph is G = {V, E U E^T}. The edges plus the reverse ones that need to be added.

Side note: changing `long` to `double` in the [push-relable example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/push_relabel_max_flow.html) worked perfectly fine.